# uploading and import csv to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dictionary, routes, paperclip, fastercsv

i have followed this tut [enter link description here](http://www.goodbadtech.com/2009/05/13/ruby-on-rails-import-csv-data-into-database/), though i seem to have encountered a few issues. the problem i am getting is

```
NameError

undefined local variable or method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007f81b1bd0170>
```

which i believe is related to the routes.rb

```
map.resources :imports
  map.import_proc '/import/proc/:id', :controller => "imports", :action => "proc_csv"
```

im using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is the keyword used for routing in Rails 2. Rails 3 routing is substantially changed. You want something more like this:

```
resources :imports do
  member do
    get :import_proc
  end
end
```

For more information, check out the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: that seems to have partly fixed it though now its doing this `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `import_proc_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff2fdc740a0>:0x007ff300112ad8>):
    8: 
    9: <% else %>
    10: 
    11:     <%= link_to "process", import_proc_path(@import.id) %>
    12: 
    13: <% end %>
  app/views/imports/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_imports_show_html_erb__3330178857390528579_70340796055700'

Comment: how do i add the action of proc_csv to what you did ?

Answer (score 1):

import_proc is a member method so you need to pass in a parameter

```
import_proc_path(id)
```

Member methods require a parameter, an ID
Collection methods does not require a parameter so it doesn't require a parameter